# How does a system like Kafka ensure ordering within a partition

Tags: architecture, apache-kafka

I was reading this [article](https://hackernoon.com/thorough-introduction-to-apache-kafka-6fbf2989bbc1) which discusses how Kafka is implemented. The article mentions that essentially each shard is a *append-only commit-log* and thats how it guarantees ordering within a partition.

Quoting the article:

> A commit log (also referred to as write-ahead log, transaction log) is
>   a persistent ordered data structure which only supports appends. You
>   cannot modify nor delete records from it. It is read from left to
>   right and guarantees item ordering.
>   [image]

What I don't understand is how Kafka makes sure it appends to the log in **the order which the user intends**. Couldn't there be a race condition where user sends in object A first and then object B but B gets written to the log first?

**NOTE**: I understand ordering can't be guaranteed across partitions. This is regarding ordering within a partition.

Side Note: According to another [article](https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying), an append-only commit-log is an abstraction for a variety of systems so this might clarify a lot of other stuff as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that the ordering guarantee holds only for  messages sent by the same producer. There's no ordering guarantee for messages  which are sent by different producers. In this scenario, the only thing that matters is the order of reception in the broker side. If you want such functionality, it has to be incorporated in the producer code itself. You can find more details in this [blog](https://blog.khangnguyen.me/2017/09/can-kafka-guarantee-message-ordering.html).

In case, you want to maintain order even if there's a failure from producer side, this might be relevant:

> Setting the retries parameter to nonzero and the
>   *max.in.flights.requests.per.session* to more than one means that it is
>   possible that the broker will fail to write the first batch of
>   messages, succeed to write the second (which was already in- flight),
>   and then retry the first batch and succeed, thereby reversing the
>   order.
>
> Usually, setting the number of retries to zero is not an option in a
>   reliable system, so if guaranteeing order is critical, we recommend
>   setting in.flight.requests.per.session=1 to make sure that while a
>   batch of messages is retrying, additional messages will not be sent
>   (because this has the potential to reverse the correct order). This
>   will severely limit the throughput of the producer, so only use this
>   when order is important.
>
> from: Kafka Definitive Guide

**UPDATE-1**

So, I did a bit of digging into the Kafka producer source-code. Apparently producer adds the records to a record [accumulator](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/RecordAccumulator.java) and then sends of all the records in the accumulator to the broker(s) after the batch is full or long enough time has passed. Each record has a timestamp associated to it. I think the broker(s) add the records in order of the timestamp to topic, and hence ensure the ordering is maintained within a partition. Someone with better knowledge of the internals of Kafka, might be able to accept to reject this hypothesis.

**UPDATE-2**

As pointed out by *cricket_007* in the comments, the order of elements fetched from the accumulator doesn't depend on the timestamp. The accumulator is a queue, so insertion and retrieval orders are the same.

Comment: I don't think if you manually set the record timestamps to be N, then N-1, etc. they will be sorted by time. The ordering is exactly the order of the send calls

Comment: @cricket_007 I see that records are appended to the accumulator by the producer. When the broker commits the records to log from the accumulator, I hope it maintains the order of insertion. In the doc of accumulator class it's mentioned that it acts as a queue. Can you confirm if my assumptions are correct?

Comment: Sure, it acts like a queue with the max batch size, but I was referring to "the broker(s) add the records in order of the timestamp", which I was saying that if you manually set the record timestamps to be in "reverse order", then they are still adding to the broker in that order, not "flipped" to be sorted in chronological order. At least, that is my understanding without digging into the internals.

Comment: Thank you :). I was trying to emphasize in my comment, if it's a queue, then for retrieval also, fifo ordering would be honored, which I guess aligns with your statement. I'll update my answer later with these points.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to point out that Kafka guarantees item ordering *in the order it was written*, not necessarily in the intended order.

In order to guarantee order you provide a key, the producer will use that key in the default [partitioner algorithm](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java#L69), it's approximately this:

```
hash(key)%numPartitions = partition
```

This is a deterministic algorithm, meaning that if the key doesn't change and the partition count doesn't change the records will always be written to the same partition, and Kafka will store the records *in the order it receives them*.

Comment: for same partition case, how is it ensured that if user sends events 1,2 in order then kafka writes them in the same order. couldn't there be race condition?

Comment: From the same producer? the producer will have them in the order you called `send()`